# Error in cross compiling for adding libpcap to mipsel

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, cross-compiling, openwrt

I compiled C and link libpcap
after adding the library. I use the following line to compile my code.

```
mipsel-openwrt-linux-gcc -c -Wall -I /home/osboxes/Downloads/OpenWrt-SDK-brcm47xx-for-Linux-i686-gcc-4.3.3+cs_uClibc-0.9.30.1/staging_dir/toolchai,n-mipsel_gcc-4.3.3+cs_uClibc-0.9.30.1/include -o sniffex.o sniffex.c
```

Output:

```
cc1: error: /home/osboxes/Downloads/OpenWrt-SDK-brcm47xx-for-Linux-i686-gcc-4.3.3+cs_uClibc-0.9.30.1/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_gcc-4.3.3+cs_uClibc-0.9.30.1/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-uclibc/4.3.3/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-uclibc/sys-include: not a directory
cc1: error: /home/osboxes/Downloads/OpenWrt-SDK-brcm47xx-for-Linux-i686-gcc-4.3.3+cs_uClibc-0.9.30.1/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_gcc-4.3.3+cs_uClibc-0.9.30.1/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-uclibc/4.3.3/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-uclibc/sys-include: not a directory
```

I tried also to do it with Makefile

Comment: _"I tried also"_ What?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something wrong. I find that the SDK was 32 bit and I have 64bit OS then I downloaded 64bit SDK and everything work well.